# CSS - Limit Max-Height of 2 Resizeable Children to Parent Viewport

Tags: html, css

Is there a way with just CSS to allow the SQL textarea to be resized, while allowing the grid containing results to be resized, but to prevent the combination from extending viewport?

The page allows providing SQL, clicking a button to run query, and returning result.  I'm using Electron to serve the content, and want to leave resizing viewport to the Electron app without having overflow off the page due to elements resizing past the viewport.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="queryForm">      
      <div class="querySetup">
        <textarea id="SQL"></textarea>        
        <button id="odbcResultsQuery">Execute Query</button>        
      </div>
      <div class="tableContainer ag-theme-alpine" id="agGrid">
        
      </div>      
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
  height: 98vh;
  width: 98vw;
}

.queryForm {
  position: relative;  
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 98vh;  
}

.querySetup {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%; 
  height: 50%;
}

.querySetup textarea {    
  height: 80%;  
  min-width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.querySetup button { 
    min-width: 100%;  
}

.querySetup input { 
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tableContainer {  
  width: 98vw;
  /*height: 49vh;
  max-height: 75vh;*/
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;  
  overflow: auto;
  resize: vertical;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr td {
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to

1. Eliminate the query setup div so that the resizeable text area was directly within the queryForm
2. In queryForm

```
.queryForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 98vh;
}

textarea#SQL {
  resize: vertical; 
}

.tableContainer {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```